# Why is my linked list object in JavaScript not updating when I try to add a node to the beginning of the list?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, factory-pattern

I'm trying to create a linked list using a factory function. When I run the method append on the list console.log displays the correct value. The prepend method on the other hand doesn't seem to be working when I console.log the resulting list. However, when I run a method to return the value of the list and log that I get the value I'm looking for. The code is as follows:

```
//linked list factory function
const LinkedListFactory = (initialNode) => {
  //declare initial value of the list
  let head = { value: initialNode.value, nextNode: initialNode.nextNode };

  //method to return list
  const giveList = () => {
    return head;
  };

  //method to return last node in list
  const getLast = () => {
    let lastNode = head;
    if (lastNode) {
      while (lastNode.nextNode) {
        lastNode = lastNode.nextNode;
      }
    }
    return lastNode;
  };

  //method to append node to the end of the list
  const append = (node) => {
    getLast().nextNode = node;
  };

  //method to add node to the front of the list (not working)
  const prepend = (node) => {
    let temp = { ...head };
    node.nextNode = temp;
    head = node;
    //gives the correct updated value of the list
    console.log(head);
  };

  return { head, append, prepend, giveList };
};

//node factory function to create data nodes
const NodeFactory = (value = null, nextNode = null) => {
  return { value, nextNode };
};

//creating test nodes
let node1 = NodeFactory("This is node 1");
let node2 = NodeFactory("This is node 2");
let node3 = NodeFactory("This is node 3");
let node4 = NodeFactory("This is node 4");

let list = LinkedListFactory(node1);
console.log(list.head);

list.append(node2);

console.log(list.head);

list.prepend(node3);

//These two statements give different values in the console
console.log(list.head);
console.log(list.giveList());
```

I did some googling to try and pin down the problem but I've had no luck so far. I expected node3 to be added to the beginning of the linked list and point to node1 which would then point to node2. When I console.log the list it only shows node1 and node2 but not node3. When I run a method to return the linked list and log it I get the value I'm looking for. I don't know why it's doing this behaviour and I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `head = node` is not actually doing what you think it is doing.

First let's have a look at the `LinkedListFactory`, which internally declares a variable `head` and initializes it with the contents of the Node that is passed to `LinkedListFactory`. After declaring the methods you return a new object with them and the `head` node in it. (I will call it the "list" from now)

JavaScript objects are always references to their underlying values. This means after `LinkedListFactory` returns, the "list" object's `head` property will point to the same value as the `head` variable that was declared in the `LinkedListFactory`.

When you, in `prepend`, set the `head` variable equal to a new `temp` Node, the "list" object's head property will still point to the original value.

To achieve what you want you need to change prepend to look like something like this:

```
function prepend(node) {
    let temp = this.head; // temp points to the old head
    this.head = node; // overwrite pointer to head on list
    this.head.nextNode = temp; // point to old head
    head = this.head; // keep head and this.head in sync
  }
```

In this case `this` will refer to the object the `prepend` function was called on, so the "list", and we can modify it.

In your implementation we are only changing what the internal variable `head` is pointing to. In this implementation we change the `head` property of the "list".

I can recommend you to have a look at these MDN pages:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

---

I thought about this a little bit more. Your implementation works, you just give a meaning to the "list"'s head property where there is none. You can simply remove it as it is only confusing:

```
//linked list factory function
const LinkedListFactory = (initialNode) => {
  //declare initial value of the list
  let head = { value: initialNode.value, nextNode: initialNode.nextNode };

  //method to return list
  const giveList = () => {
    return head;
  };

  //method to return last node in list
  const getLast = () => {
    let lastNode = head;
    if (lastNode) {
      while (lastNode.nextNode) {
        lastNode = lastNode.nextNode;
      }
    }
    return lastNode;
  };

  //method to append node to the end of the list
  const append = (node) => {
    getLast().nextNode = node;
  };

  //method to add node to the front of the list (not working)
  const prepend = (node) => {
    let temp = { ...head };
    node.nextNode = temp;
    head = node;
    //gives the correct updated value of the list
    console.log(head);
  };

  return { append, prepend, get head() { return giveList(); } }; // I aliased giveList to a `head` getter
};

//node factory function to create data nodes
const NodeFactory = (value = null, nextNode = null) => {
  return { value, nextNode };
};

//creating test nodes
let node1 = NodeFactory("This is node 1");
let node2 = NodeFactory("This is node 2");
let node3 = NodeFactory("This is node 3");
let node4 = NodeFactory("This is node 4");

let list = LinkedListFactory(node1);
console.log(list.head);

list.append(node2);

console.log(list.head);

list.prepend(node3);

console.log(list.head);
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. The refactored code worked for me. I'm going to have to over the code and the resources you provided to get a full understanding. I appreciate the time you took to help